# strtotime display one date before in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime, php-5.5

I've a date in the format dd/mm/YYYY. Eg: 25/06/2015.
I want convert it to timestamp. I've added the following code to implement this;

```
$timestamp = strtotime( str_replace( '/', '-', '25/06/2015' ) );
```

It creates timestamp, but when I convert that timestamp I can see that it is one day before. When I execute the above code, I got the timestamp value "1435183200". When I convert this I got the previous date "24/06/2015".

If anybody knows the solution to fix this, please help.

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/382598). Make sure your timezone settings are correct.

Comment: I've a European timezone.

Comment: as per strototime docs: `Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended`. did you set a default time zone? Is that timezone the same as wherever this date came from? just because it's june 25th, doesn't mean it's june 25th in the world at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the default timezone configured in PHP. Try switching your timezone. Use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('your_timezone_here');
```

For a list of supported timezones, go to http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php